# Nodemon + Vagrant + Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vagrant, nodemon

I'm using Vagrant for developing my node apps, I have installed nodemon, mongodb and fwded ports 3000:3000 (for my apps) and 27017:27017 (for MongoDB connection).

If I run

```
nodemon server.js
```

And I can access my app on `http://localhost:3000`, but every time I make a change on my Vm's DB I have to type

```
rs
```

For the changes on the DB to take effect on `http://localhost:3000`

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: As a workaround, you can try watching the files for change on the host machine and find a way to restart the server remotely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995590/auto-starting-node-js-application-on-vagrant-when-there-are-changes-to-the-code

Comment: nodemon listens for filesystem "notify" events from the Linux Kernel. As the filesystem used by vagrant/virtual box does not support "notify" events, nodemon does not work. It's as simple as that. Using the "-L" flag will tell nodemon to pull for changes as a certain interval, which will make it work. Less efficient though.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem, 
There is an open issue for this bug in github (https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/146).

With the `-L`, it work, but it take 3, 4 seconds to restart after a change.

`nodemon -L server.js`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I know that it's not the best answer, but he use nodemon with vagrant, and nodemon doesn't work properly (with vagrant) if you don't use the `-L` flag like I said in my answer. For me, if I don't do that, I need to type `rs` all the time I make change, like Alejandronanez.

Comment: The `-L` flag consumed too much CPU for me.

Comment: after 8 years, this still seems to be a solution. "-L" hasn't consumed any extra CPU for me.